# How to recompile an Angular 1.x directive that uses "replace: true"

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, cloudinary

**Summary**

I am using a third party directive that configures `replace: true`.

I want to recompile the directive every time the user clicks a button.  I've tried several things without luck.  For example, I tried wrapping the Cloudinary directive in my own directive, but I can't seem to get it.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

**Dependencies**

```
"angular": "1.6.2",
"cloudinary-core": "^2.5.0",
"cloudinary_ng": "^1.1.1",
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.rotate = (leader) => {
  leader.cloudinary_angle = {
    '0': '90',
    '90': '180',
    '180': '270',
    '270': '0'
  }[leader.cloudinary_angle] || '0';
};
```

**View**

```
<div ng-repeat="leader in leaders">
  <a href="#" ng-click="rotate(leader)">Rotate</a>
  <cloudimage leader="leader"></cloudimage>
</div>
```

**Did not work #1**

```
angular.module('app').directive('cloudimage', ($compile) => {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: false,
    scope: {
      leader: '='
    },
    link: (scope, element) => {

      let cloudinaryImage = $compile('<cl-image angle="' + scope.leader.cloudinary_angle + '"' +
                                              ' crop="fit"' +
                                              ' format="jpg"' +
                                              ' height="150"' +
                                              ' public-id="' + scope.leader.cloudinary + '"' +
                                              ' quality="80"' +
                                              ' width="150"' +
                                      '></cl-image>'
                            )(scope);

      element.html(cloudinaryImage[0]);

      scope.$watch('scope.leader.cloudinary_angle', (cloudinaryImage) => element.html(cloudinaryImage[0]));
    }
  };
});
```

**Did not work #2**

```
angular.module('app').directive('cloudimage', ($compile) => {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: false,
    scope: {
      leader: '='
    },
    template: '<cl-image crop="fit" format="jpg" height="150" angle="{{angle}}" public-id="{{id}}" quality="80" width="150"></cl-image>',
    link: (scope, element) => {
      scope.angle = scope.leader.cloudinary_angle || 0;
      scope.id = scope.leader.cloudinary;
    }
  };
});
```

**Did not work #3**

I can decorate the 3rd party directive to make its `replace: false`, but that breaks its transclude.

```
angular.module('app').config(['$provide', function($provide) {
  $provide.decorator('clImageDirective', function($delegate) {
      var directive = $delegate[0];    
      directive.replace = false;
      return $delegate;
  })
}]);
```

Comment: Does cl-image really need replace: true? You could extend it and make it replace: false.

Comment: I tried that approach also, but was unable to get it to work.  I think I may know why it wasn't working though.  Tonight when I get home I will try to decorate the directive again and post code if I still can't get it.

Comment: I am able to decorate the directive to make `replace: false`, but when I do that the `cl-image` directive does not properly transclude and the image does not show.

Comment: I see.The code you've posted doesn't contain a button. Basically, you need to do $compile() inside event listener.

Comment: I added some of the code from the controller and the view.  Hopefully it makes more sense now.  When I click "rotate" it does update `leader.cloudinary_angle` in the view.  I put a watch on this in the directive (see "Did Not Work #1").  Instead of getting the new image I get `<cloudimage leader="leader" class="ng-isolate-scope">[object HTMLImageElement]</cloudimage>` in the view.

Comment: Yes, a decorator could work. #1 doesn't work because `html()` expects a string, not DOM element. And you shouldn't convert it to string, this will destroy dynamic behaviour of a directive. It should be something like `element.empty().append(cloudinaryImage)`.

Comment: Oh, you're right... `element.html()` is expecting a string.  That's the issue.  This solution works.  Post it as an answer and I'll accept it.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#1` doesn't work because `html()` expects a string, not DOM element. `cloudinaryImage` element shouldn't be converted to a string because this will destroy information about the element.

It should be:

```
scope.$watch('scope.leader.cloudinary_angle', (cloudinaryImage) => { 
  element.empty().append(cloudinaryImage)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Time for dirty hacks... You can recompile anything (including one-time bindings, any directive) using ng-repeat on array with single element:

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl" ng-init="arr = [{}]">
    <button ng-click="arr = [{}]">Recompile</button>
    <p test ng-repeat="o in arr"></p>
  </body>
```

where test directive is

```
app.directive('test', function() {
  return {
    replace: true,
    template: '<span>hello</span>',
    link: function() {
      console.log('I am linked');
    }
  }
})
```

P.S. you can do pretty same with ng-if, but then you will require 2 digests.
P.P.S. I agree this is kinda weird.

http://plnkr.co/edit/vlC7TV8eIrW1tLgcvP7Y?p=preview